# How to make the keyboard interact with a website within the Android app's webview?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an application that contains a web view. You open my website. My site contains a search. When you open the website inside the web view and write any word, then press the word search or done inside the keyboard, the matter is not executed unless the user removes the keyboard and presses on the word Search within the site and this is very, very annoying for users.

But if you open the site from an external application, for example, Chrome, it works normally

My application is programmed using xamarin.forms

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you mean. You mean when click "done" in the key board, it doesn't execute search operation? And could you provide some relevant code ?